# @DataJpaTest not updating property annotated with @Version

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue with one test checking that the entity with property version (annotated with `@Version`) is incremented after an update.

- If I use the annotation `@SpringBootTest` the version is incremented.
- If I use `@DataJpaTest`, the version is not incremented.

Do you know how to configure the `@DataJpaTest` to make the incrementation work?

Please find below the working test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestAuditing extends TestCrud<AuditingEntity> {

    ...

    @Test
    @Override
    void update() {
        Long version = entity.getVersion();
        super.update();
        assertEquals(++version, entity.getVersion());
    }
}
```

And here is the not working test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class TestAuditing extends TestCrud<AuditingEntity> {
    
    ...

    @Test
    @Override
    void update() {
        Long version = entity.getVersion();
        super.update();
        assertEquals(++version, entity.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the TestCrud abstract class

```
public abstract class TestCrud<E extends AbstractEntity> {

    protected static AbstractEntity entity;

    ...

    @Test
    void update() {
        E updatedEntity = crudAdapter.update((E) entity);
        assertEquals(updatedEntity.getId(), entity.getId());
        entity = updatedEntity;
    }
    ...
```

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: what `super.update()` do?

Comment: Hello @Antoniossss, I just added the abstract test class, in my question. It should be more clear now. It's a simple test on a adapter. Update operation in a CRUD service.

Comment: What is `crudAdapter` and what does its `update` method do? Can you simplify the code to get rid of all the indirection?

Comment: @Blackarrow you have replaced one unknown with another unknown ;) I want to know what your custom code look alike. You can stop once you get to the jpa layer;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give a definitive answer because you didn't posted the code that actually is supposed to do anything. But the likely cause of the problem is that `DataJpaTest` includes the `@Transactioanl` annotation, thus moving the transaction boundaries from the entry and exit of the repository method, which I assume you use somewhere to the test method. Since JPA doesn't flush changes until the end of the transaction you don't get a version increment.

For tests like yours which depends on the exact scope of transactions I recommend using a `TransactionTemplate`, so that you have exact control over your transactions. You can also use SQL logging to ensure that SQL statements get executed when you think they get executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was definitely the issue. To add  `@Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED) ` on my tests fixed the issue.